# How to create a Bottom Sheet dialog that occupy the 80 percent of the screen in Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to make a modal that takes up 80 percent of the screen regardless of the content.
My idea is to be able to achieve something like this

[image]

In this moment I have this

MainActivity.kt

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialog

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Get the button view and set a click listener on it
        val btnPressMe = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnPressMe)
        btnPressMe.setOnClickListener {
            // Create the bottom sheet dialog
            val bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(this)

            // Inflate the layout for the bottom sheet dialog
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog, null)

            // Set the content view of the bottom sheet dialog
            bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view)

            // Set the peek height of the bottom sheet dialog to 80% of the screen height
            val behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(view.parent as View)
            behavior.peekHeight = (resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.8).toInt()

            // Show the bottom sheet dialog
            bottomSheetDialog.show()
        }
    }
}
```

bottom_sheet_dialog.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPressMe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press Me"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the result is this

[image]

Any ideas to achieve the goal?
Thank you!